# Transform $f(t)=\exp\bigg(\frac{1}{\log(t)}\bigg)$ into a differential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, recreational-mathematics, laplace-transform, transformation

In mathematics, the Laplace transform, named after its inventor Pierre-Simon Laplace is an integral transform that converts a function of a real variable ${\displaystyle t}$ (often time) to a function of a complex variable ${\displaystyle s}$ (complex frequency). The transform has many applications in science and engineering because it is a tool for solving differential equations. In particular, it transforms differential equations into algebraic equations and convolution into multiplication.

`Okay, but what if there's an image of an algebraic equation?`.... $f(t)$ and you want to turn it into some diff eq.? The algebraic equation is $h(t)=1/t$ and $f(t)$ is the image under $f:\Bbb R^2 \to\Bbb R^2$ with $f(\exp(t),\exp(t)).$

> So how do I transform a function $f(t)=\exp\bigg(\frac{1}{\log(t)}\bigg)$ into a function of a complex variable using a transform?

This is highly important to me because of physical reasons. My colleague advised me to look into transforms such as the fourier, laplace, and mellin transforms.

My thought is $$ f(s)=\int_0^1 f(t)K(s,t)~dt $$

Comment: I think the Laplace Transform on that function would be a problem.  At t=1, the function has different limits depending on how you get there.  From the left, you get zero, from the right, infinity.  Doing a test numerical integration (with s=2) on Wolfram Alpha, the numerical integral $\int_0^\infty e^{\frac{1}{log(t)}} e^{-2t} dt$ doesn't converge.

Comment: @DavidElm you're right, the laplace transform is inadequate due to the way it's defined. unfortunately I'm at a loss as to how to properly define a transform that converts $f(t)$ into $f(s).$ Could be impossible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trouble of  log t at $t=1$ can be avoided with usual (untransformed LT ) ODE? Only a comment.
$$e^{f(t)}= \dfrac{1}{\log t}$$

$${\log t}= e^{-f(t)}$$

Differentiate

$$\frac{1}{t} = -e^{-f(t)}{f'(t)}$$
$$f'(t)=\dfrac{-e^{f(t)}}{t}=\dfrac{-1}{t\, \log t}$$